# Parsing a JSON Stringified variable returns the value undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, wit-ai

The code below is the entirety of my discord.js [`message` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message), I am using [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) as well as [node-wit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wit). When wit identifies a message including a math expression, it will evaluate the value and send it back to the user.

It sends back data using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). However when I try and parse it, everything I log only returns `undefined.`

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 wClient
  .message(message.content, {})
  .then((data) => {
   const response = JSON.stringify(data, ['intents', 'name', 'confidence']);
   const responseParsed = JSON.parse(response);

   console.log(response);
   console.log(responseParsed);

   if (responseParsed.name == 'Math') {
    message.channel.send(eval(data));
   }
  })
  .catch(console.error);
});
```

The actual response of the console logs for the `JSON.stringify()` and then the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) are listed below:

**`JSON.Stringify()`**

```
{"intents":[{"name":"Math","confidence":0.9945}]}
```

**`JSON.parse()`**

```
{ intents: [ { name: 'Math', confidence: 0.9945 } ] }
```

Comment: `responseParsed` does not have a `name` property... (and why use `eval`?)

Comment: I tried that earlier, it returns `undefined`. I changed it back to not using the property so that I could show what it was returning as a whole.

Comment: what is `wClient`.

Comment: I used eval because Wit returns the message with what is believes the intent is, it doesn't actually pick out the mathematical expression it detects, eval was the only way I could find to take a string and use it as a mathematical expression.

Comment: @DanielA.White I declared wClient as `const wClient = new Wit({accessToken: TOKEN})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this structure

```
 { intents: [ { name: 'Math', confidence: 0.9945 } ] }
```

I assume that this is how it should be
to try

```
 if (responseParsed.intents[0].name == 'Math') {
message.channel.send(eval(data));
```

}